# Cannot Connect to Internal Network

Tags: networking, internet

I just got a System76 Gazelle laptop with Ubuntu 13.10. I can connect to the internet via a wired ethernet. But I CANNOT connect to my wired ethernet internal network. I have a file server (internal network) that has its own ip address and my Gazelle does not see the connection.

I can connect to the network with my Windows XP Dell laptop. What do I have to do to connect to my internet network with my Gazelle? Please help!

Here is my ipconfig.

```
bioscorpion@bioscorpion-Gazelle-Professional:~$ ifconfig
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:f4:8d:9d  
        inet6 addr: fe80::290:f5ff:fef4:8d9d/64 Scope:Link  
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
        RX packets:8891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
        TX packets:7933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
        RX bytes:8377799 (8.3 MB)  TX bytes:1326689 (1.3 MB)  

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:69868 (69.8 KB)  TX bytes:69868 (69.8 KB)
```

Comment: I see nothing for IPv4 in your `eth0` info - have you checked your Network Settings to make sure that you something set there to get a standard IPv4 connection, either with DHCP or a static IP?

Answer (score 1):

I had to go under "Edit Connections" add a new network and set the IP4 settings Method to "Manual" and then enter Address field with my internal network IP address and Netmask.

Now I can see my internal network hard drive!

Thank you for all your answers.